# .NET page controls rendering in IE8, FireFox and Chrome after Refresh

Tags: .net, firefox, google-chrome, rendering

The main problem is that my pages do not render properly in Firefox and Chrome, but render perfectly in IE8. When you view the pages in Firefox, the controls (a few custom controls and linkbuttons) do not render until you do a manual refresh. In IE8, they render the first time.

Any thoughts guys what could cause this?

The linkbuttons are not dynamically added to the page, but the custom controls are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to run the ws in debug mode put a breakpoint on the load/init of the page and check if the breakpoint is hit in chrome too (it looks like it does in IE8 by your description), it maybe some js ould be the cause, too few info at the moment.